# Does the %rax register contain the return value of function right after the 'call' instruction?

Tags: segmentation-fault, malloc, disassembly

this is a simple disassembly code.

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp
movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
mov    $0xf,%edi
callq  1070 <malloc@plt>
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
mov    %rax,%rdi
callq  1060 <free@plt>
mov    $0x0,%eax
```

Does the return value of malloc function is restored in the rax register right after the `callq  1070 <malloc@plt>` ?
I instrumented code that calls `malloc_usable_size` to get the malloced size of the `malloc` function, but it encountered `segmentation fault`. I thought that I transfer a wrong address to `malloc_usable_size`.

For `str = (char *) malloc(15);`, Does the value `str` is saved in the %rax?
What I want to ask is: if the value of `str` is restored in %rax right after `callq  1070 <malloc@plt>` and before `mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)`?  Can use the value of %rax to get the information of malloced area, such as the size of malloced area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to ask is: if the value of str is restored in %rax right after `callq  1070 <malloc@plt>` and before `mov %rax,-0x8(%rbp)`?

Your question is exceedingly unclear.

The `str` variable resides in memory at address `rpb[-8]`. Immediately after the `malloc` returns, register `rax` contains the `malloc` return value, and that value is *stored* in the memory at address `rbp[-8]` (i.e. it is stored in `str`).

Note that your disassembly is using AT&T syntax. This instruction `mov %rax,-0x8(%rbp)` stores value in in `rax` at location `rpb[-8]`.

Comment: Yes, what you said is right. What I want to do is instrument code to get the assigned size of '`str' using malloc_usable_size. The problem has been solved. I did transfer a wrong address to malloc_usable_size. Thanks for your answer.